# How does the DB2 .prepare() function work within Node?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I am attempting to setup prepared insert statements but I am having difficulty finding documentation on using DB2i with Node.

I found a website that shows how I would assume the function would work..

```
var db = require('/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OPS/Node4/os400/db2i/lib/db2');
var data = {};


db.init();
db.conn(config.db_name);

db.prepare(query, function(err, stmt) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
        console.log(stmt);
    }
```

The issue is, stmt comes back as undefined and there is no error. I am very confused on how I am supposed to setup this function and I can't find documentation anywhere.

I have also done a

```
console.log(db.prepare.toString());
```

It shows a function exists.

Answer (score 0):

`prepare` is used together with `bindParam` and `execute`. [Example](https://github.com/IBM/nodejs-idb-connector/blob/master/docs/README.md#async-prepare-bind-execute) from the [docs](https://github.com/IBM/nodejs-idb-connector/blob/master/docs/README.md#dbstmtpreparesql-callback):

```
const sql = 'call QXMLSERV.iPLUG512K(?,?,?,?)';
// note 4 params
const params = [[ipc, IN, CHAR],
  [ctl, IN, CHAR],
  [xmlIn, IN, CLOB],
  [xmlOut, OUT, CLOB],
];

const statement = new dbstmt(connection);

statement.prepare(sql, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  statement.bindParam(params, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    statement.execute((out, error) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      statement.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my issue now is that I receive the following error:  qsh: 001-0078 Process ended by signal 5.

Comment: you could checkout https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1020591 if that doesn't help you could ask new question